# JQuery mobile, How to add two or more anchors to a li element?

Tags: css, html, jquery-mobile

Does anyone can create a JSfiddle code to demonstrate how to integrate two or more anchor tags in the same `li` item? I have searched but no clear answer of how could you for instance divide the `li` element with lets say 3 square anchors 1/3 each. Do you for example need to add `div` tags to each anchor?

eg.

```
<ul>
 <li>
   <a href= "#anchor1"></a>
   <a href= "#anchor2"></a>
   <a href= "#anchor3"></a>
 </li>
 <li>
   <a href= "#anchor1"></a>
   <a href= "#anchor2"></a>
   <a href= "#anchor3"></a>
 </li>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Anchor tags lead to anchor points somewhere else on the page. I think you are talking about something different.

Comment: @Andi: Lets say that you have included a picture, text and an a button to delete. The picture should take you to the profile, the text in the middle to the post page and the delete button to a popup window. So how to include the three anchor tags using JQuery mobile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the jQuery Mobile grid:

> http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/grids/

e.g.:

```
<li>
    <div class="ui-grid-b">
        <div class="ui-block-a">
            <a href= "#anchor1"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/80/80/food/1/" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-block-b">
            <a href= "#anchor1" class="ui-btn">Some text</a>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-block-c">
            <a href= "#anchor1" class="ui-btn"> Delete</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

> Here is a simple **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/w6w9b90w/)**

NOTE: you can then use CSS to tweak widths, margins, padding, etc. to taste.

Answer (score -1):

Let's say, as you asked, you have 3 elements:

```
<div class="your_three_elements">
  <a href="linktoprofile.html"><img src="..." alt="..." /></a>
  <a href="linktopostpage.html">Your Text</a>
  <a href="#" onClick="openPopup()">Your Button</a>
</div>
```

So you have to have one link per one target. But those things aren't anchors. An anchor would be something like this:

```
<div class"your_anchorlink">
  <a href="#gototext">Your Link</a>
</div>
<div id="gototext">
When you click on the link, you will get to this text (which is on the same page).
</div>
```

You could combine that by having a link go_to_some_page.html#gototext which will open the go_to_some_page page and jump to the id gototext.

But maybe I am missunderstanding what you want to do.

Comment: Well @Andi, you are right. They should be links :), however how do you do it within a `li` element in Jquery mobile?